# How to add icon in ag-grid column header?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid

i have develop an ag-grid tabel and on the table header column i wanted to add an icon just beside the header name, as shown in below image

[image: sample image]

how to achieve the above functionality with ag-grid.

i have tried using menuIcon inside the column array.

```
const columns = [
    {
        autoHeight: true
        sortingOrder: ["desc", "asc", null],
        minWidth: 200,
        width: 200,
        headerComponentParams : {
            // hear i have tried to use menuIcon
        }
    }]
```

but not able to place the icon there, looking for the solution how to add icon in the ag-grid header column.

Answer (score 0):

use it this way

```js
{
     headerName: '',
     headerComponentParams: { template: `
                                   <div>
                                       <span>
                                         sample <i class="fa fa-star"> 
                                                </i>
                                        </span>
                                   </div>`},
     field: "bookmarked",
     minWidth: 200,
     width: 200,
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).